# crear un array del tamaño ingresado con input en js

Tags: javascript

me pueden ayudar con un ejercicio de js en el que pueda crear un array del tamaño ingresado en un input y que se muestre en orden ascendente pero en numeros aleatorios hasta el 100

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], edita y muestra lo que llevas y los errores que tienes, las preguntas del tipo necesito hacer esto pero que no vienen acompañadas de un avance por parte del OP(tu), terminan cerradas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// target a los elementos del DOM por id
const $inputNumber = document.getElementById('input-number')
const $btnGenerate = document.getElementById('btn-generate')
const $listNumbers = document.getElementById('list-numbers')

const randomNumberLimit = 100

// listener al evento click del boton
$btnGenerate.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let inputNumberValue = $inputNumber.value
  let counter = 0
  let arrayNumbers = []
  // counter incrementa mientras sea menor que inputNumberValue
  while (counter++ < inputNumberValue) {
    // inserta números aleatorios dentro del array arrayNumbers
    arrayNumbers.push(getRandomNumber())
  }
  sortAscNumbers(arrayNumbers)
  appendNumbersOnList(arrayNumbers)
})

// retorna un número random entre 0 y randomNumberLimit
function getRandomNumber () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (randomNumberLimit + 1))
}

// ordena ascendentemente un array de números
function sortAscNumbers (numbers) {
  return numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b)
}

// inserta los números en elementos <li> dentro de <ul id="list-numbers"></ul>
function appendNumbersOnList (numbers) {
  let items = ''
  numbers.forEach(n => (items += `<li>${n}</li>`))
  $listNumbers.innerHTML = items
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input-number">
<button id="btn-generate">
  generate
</button>
<ul id="list-numbers">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Este código que hice en JavaScript donde crea un arreglo variable desde la entrada de un input
- Genera un `random` aleatorio de numero enteros de 1 a 100
- Muestra el contenido, ordena el `array` en forma ascendente y muestra nuevamente el arreglo ya ordenado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Cantidad items: </label>
    <input type="number" id='cantidad' value="0">
    <button id="boton">Correr</button>
    <br>
    <p>arreglo creados:</p>
        <div id='creado'>
        </div>
    <p>arreglo ordenado ACENDENTE:</p>
        <div id='ordenado'>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // funcion para comparar Corrige orden para numero de un digito
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort
        function comparar(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        }

        // funcion para mostrar el arreglo
        function mostrarArreglo(elemento, arreglo) {
            document.getElementById(elemento).innerHTML=""; // limpiar DIV
            for (let index = 0; index < arreglo.length; index++) {
               var numeros = document.createElement("P"); // crear element P
               numeros.innerHTML ='[' + index + '] => '+ arreglo[index]; // poner valor a element P
               document.getElementById(elemento).appendChild(numeros);   // agregar elemenmto P    
            }
        }

        // evento de click boton correr
        document.getElementById("boton").onclick = function() {
            var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
            var arreglo = []; // inicializar 
            

            // crea el arreglo con la cantidad tipeada
            for (let index = 0; index < cantidad; index++) {
                // agrega un item de arreglo y crear el contenido con random entero de 1 a 100
                arreglo.push(parseInt((Math.random() * 100) + 1));              
            }

            // mostrar contenido de arreglo SIN ORDENAR
            mostrarArreglo('creado', arreglo);

            // ordenar arreglo ASCENDENTE
            arreglo.sort(comparar);

            // mostrar contenido de arreglo ORDENADO
            mostrarArreglo('ordenado', arreglo);

        };

     </script> 
</body>
</html>
```